# `scipy.signal.find_peaks` Prominence Issue

Tags: python, scipy, max

I'm writing a script that finds max winds based on specific requirements. The problem I'm having is one of the requirements to be a max wind peak; the prominence must be equal to or greater than 19.4384.

relevant code

```
    velocity=np.array(self.df['SPEED'])
    for m in range(len(velocity)):  
        if velocity[m] == 999.9 or np.isnan(velocity[m]):
            velocity[m]=velocity[m-1]
    max_velocity=find_peaks(velocity, height=58.3152, prominence=19.4384, plateau_size=0)
```

The velocity array length is over 6000 elements long, so only showing the relevant selection.

Index of velocity
[...,2268,2269,2270,2271,2272,2273,2274,2275,2276,2277,2278,2279,2280,2281,2282,2283,2284,2285,2286,2287,2288,2289,2290,2291,2292,2293,2294,2295,2296,2297, ...]

Velocity wind speed data
[...,106.0,106.0,106.0,106.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,106.0,106.0,106.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,106.0,...]

max_velocity =

**Index** , **Type**, **Size**, **Value**

0, in64, (4,),[2275,2289,2794,3247]

1, dict, 7, {'plateau_sizes': array([ 8, 14,  8, 12], dtype=int64), 'left_edges': array([2272, 2283, 2791, 3242], dtype=int64), 'right_edges': array([2279, 2296, 2798, 3253], dtype=int64), 'peak_heights': array([107., 107.,  78.,  77.]), 'prominences': array([101., 101.,  25.,  20.]), 'left_bases': array([   2,    2, 2461, 3193], dtype=int64), 'right_bases': array([4516, 4516, 4516, 4516], dtype=int64)}

I have used this script on a dozen other wind speed arrays it worked fine with them. I think the problem is caused by the valley between 2275 and 2289 is only decreasing by 1 knot. So the goal is to have the script only grab index 2275 and pass over index 2289 as it has only a prominence of one.

The other peaks found in max_velocity are correct.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to reproduce the problem given the data you've provided. Could you at least add enough for reproducibility

Comment: Please cross-check with [peak_prominences](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.peak_prominences.html).

Comment: Yes, I have been referencing the peak_prominences documentation. But I was unable to find anything that would describe the issue that I'm having eliminating the second peak.

Comment: I meant change the prominence in your function call and check if the according peaks are detected. Try a higher and lower value than you are using at the moment.

Comment: Please also check the definition of prominence used in find_peaks. Maybe you need different values for threshold and plateau_size.

Comment: So I don't want to require a spacing distance between the peaks. As in the future, there could be an approved max wind peak within 25 spaces(unlikely but possible) . Any number I pick would be arbitrary, so threshold is not a possible parameter to include. Currently, plateau_size is not doing anything. I was playing around with it to see if I could fix the second peak, but it was not helping. Since plateau_size is set to zero, it is including any max peak value. I would like to keep it that way so that if there is a peak with only one max value, it is included in the max_velocity.

Answer (score 0):

From your full data that you posted a couple of days ago, it seems that the problem is caused by ambiguity of the two peaks `2275` and `2289`. Both are reasonable candidates for the *"true"* peak.

A solution would be to handle this special case. In this case, which one would you deem to be the *"true"* peak?

For illustration:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.plot(velocity)
for i in range(len(max_velocity)):
    plt.plot(max_velocity[0], np.zeros(max_velocity[0].shape), 'ro')

plt.xlim([2200, 2400])
plt.show()
```

[image: Two peaks]

Comment: Thanks, Jen, for replying back. As I stated in my question, I know that 2275 is my true peak. So I wanted to understand why it is selecting 2289 additionally since there has been a decrease of 1 between them, failing the prominence variable of 19.4384. I agree the easy answer would be to built a special case for this event, but I have 100+ wind speed files to go through, so I rather not be forced to double-check them. I want to understand the problem and try to fix it for future files.

Comment: But what defines the first peak of the two illustrated as the "true" peak? If you can formulate a definition for that, then should have your solution. From how I see it, there is nothing in the data you have provided that solves the ambiguity to which peak is the true peak. Surely the problem is caused by the small valley with 1 in depth between 2275 and 2289.

Comment: The definition of 2275 being first is the reason it is the correct max wind, it as the prominence of 19.4384 and a height greater 58.3. The requirements for 2289 are the same; it needs to have a prominence of 19.4384 in between 2275 and 2289 and have a wind speed higher than 58.3 to be selected as a legitimate max wind peak. I agree that the valley of 1 is the issue of why both are being selected. That is why I posted the question, hoping that someone would know why scipy.find_peaks was selecting both when the code I wrote states that there needs to have 19.4384 prominences to be chosen.

Comment: Well, it would be related to how the bases are handled when calculating the prominence, from line `234` in https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/signal/_peak_finding_utils.pyx you can see the algorithm determining the bases from which the prominence would be calculated. Both are being selected as they are exactly same height and the one peak cannot be determined "parent" of the other. You could surely define some logic to handle this case, that would automate the process of finding the peaks for your 100+ wspeed files.